# Onclick doesn't work worth audio.js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am troubleshooting a [website](http://mixloops.minnebyte.com/) that uses [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) as an audio player. I am trying to configure the audio player's [event callbacks](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/) using the click method, but it is not recognizing my click.
It does however work like it should on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKAFP/20/). Any help is greatly appreciated

What I've done - 
Eliminated all CSS and irrelevant scripts.
Click method works on divs before and after the audiojs class.

Shortcode that I'm using for the audio player -

```
// audio player
add_shortcode( 'sp_audio', 'sp_audio_shortcode' );
function sp_audio_shortcode( $atts, $contents = null ) 
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 'sp-audio-player',
        'url' => '',
        ),
        $atts ) );


    $output .= '<audio preload="none">';
        $output .= '<source src="' . $url . '" type="audio/mpeg">';
    $output .= '</audio>';

    return $output;
}
```

Output in Chrome's inspect element

```
<div class="musicplayer">
<div class="audiojs" classname="audiojs" id="audiojs_wrapper5">
    <audio preload="none">
        <source src="http://soundtrackloops.com/Demo/Electronisounds-AcousticBarefootBeats-DEMO.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>          
    <div class="play-pause">             
        <p class="play"></p>             
        <p class="pause"></p>             
        <p class="loading"></p>             
        <p class="error"></p>          
    </div>           
    <div class="scrubber">             
        <div class="progress"></div>             
        <div class="loaded"></div>           
    </div>           
    <div class="time">             
        <em class="played">00:00</em>/<strong class="duration">00:00</strong>           
    </div>           
    <div class="error-message"></div>
</div>
```

My test click method

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

$( ".audiojs" ).click(function() {
  alert( "CLICK" );
});
```

Initialize audio.js

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    audiojs.createAll();
});
```

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle with your code.

Comment: It's in the description

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're appending the audio track after the page has loaded so you'll need to use a live click event.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

$('.audiojs').live('click', function() {
  alert( "CLICK" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by using event listeners on the audio object. I guess it depends on what you want to track but that gives you control over playing and stopping etc.

I adapted my code so it should be working with yours

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
var as = audiojs.createAll();

$(".audiojs audio").on('playing',function(){
    console.log("Push playing");
});

    // Other callbacks
});
```

Hope you get it working. I only have one player per page, if you have more just use the $(this) element in the callback to identify which has been altered.